# $\int_{a}^{+\infty}f(x)dx$ and $\int_{a}^{+\infty}f'(x)dx$ are convergent. Prove $f(x)\to0$.

Tags: calculus, real-analysis, integration, analysis

Assume the improper integral $\int_{a}^{+\infty}f(x)dx$ and $\int_{a}^{+\infty}f'(x)dx$ are both convergent. Show that$$\lim_{x\to+\infty}f(x)=0.$$
I just know that's right when $f'(x)$ is continuous. But I have no idea how to deal with $\int_{0}^{+\infty}f'(x)dx$ if $f'(x)$ is not continuous.

Answer (score 4, accepted):

By the fundamental theorem of calculus 
$$f(x)=f(y)-\int_x^y f'(t)\, dt.$$
Since $\int_a^\infty f(x)\, dx$ is finite you have that 
$$\liminf_{x\to\infty}|f(x)|=0$$ since otherwise $|f(x)|\ge c $ for all $x$ large which would imply that $\int_a^\infty f(x)\, dx$  is not finite. Hence you can find a sequence $y_n\to \infty$ such that $f(y_n)\to 0$. Then 
$$f(x)=f(y_n)-\int_x^{y_n} f'(t)\, dt.$$
Letting $n\to \infty$ gives $$f(x)=-\int_x^{\infty} f'(t)\, dt.$$
Letting $x\to\infty$ it follows that
$$\lim_{x\to\infty}f(x)=\lim_{x\to\infty}-\int_x^{\infty} f'(t)\, dt=0$$ since $\int_a^\infty f'(x)\, dx$ is finite.

Comment: Thanks a lot! I overlooked $f'$ is integrable, so that I was not sure $\int_{a}^{+\infty}f'(x)dx=f(+\infty)-f(a)$.